# AppEngine PHP environment in developement Error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I have got an error.
using my "php.ini" in application root. as below...

[php.ini]

```
html_errors = "Off"
display_errors = "Off"
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE
auto_prepend_file = "configure.php"
```

[error]

```
ERROR    2014-08-25 03:20:57,158 php_runtime.py:226] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 222, in new_instance
    self._runtime_config_getter().application_root)
  File "/home/foo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 195, in _check_environment
    raise _PHPEnvironmentError(check_process_stdout)
_PHPEnvironmentError
```

I can get this error during using php_runtime.py not customized.
this error is nothing when I editted this line.

[original]

```
186     args = [php_executable_path, '-c', application_root, '-f',
187             _CHECK_ENVIRONMENT_SCRIPT_PATH]
```

[customized]

```
186     args = [php_executable_path, '-f',
187             _CHECK_ENVIRONMENT_SCRIPT_PATH]
```

("-c option" is disable)

my php's option "auto_prepend_file" is murder.
but I have had no ideas.
I need "auto_prepend_file" for autoloading without to put including init file in head of every source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the php_runtime.py file is not recommended, the -c option is the path to a directory to read the php.ini file from, which App Engine probably sets to your applications directory.

By removing it your error is going away because the development server is most likely no longer reading your php.ini file, but using defaults.

I have tried using auto_prepend_file myself, and I cannot get it to work either. This looks like a bug in App Engine itself. There does not appear to be any existing issues about it logged on the [App Engine bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list), you should go and log one yourself.

Comment: yes; Editing the script is too BAD, I think so, too. I have posted this problem at [App Engine bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11245&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log). thanks, your help.